# c++: Run a function 8 times and add each answer to an array or JSON it

Tags: c++, json, string, sockets

I'm super new to C++ and am trying to build a json file that contains x0...x7 of the files that gets parsed from a pre-defined function so that it can compose a JSON string to give to R. so that it can open a socket to R and send this piece of JSON to it.

however, im kinda stuck here, here is what i have:

```
    std::map<std::string,std::string>::const_iterator   qIter;
    std::string variable;
    std::map<string,string> mymap;
    variable = "x";
    for (int i=1,i<=7,i++){
        float variable+i = ( (qIter = request.getQuery().find(variable+i))
             == request.getQuery().end()
           )
               ? 0.0
           : atof(qIter->second.c_str());

        if  ( !isLegalNumber(request.getQuery(),variable+i,variable+i) )
        {
          strcpy(filePath,"yourErrorFilename.html");
        }
        else
        {
          // I want to add the x0 or xn variable here into a json

          // The value is now in variable 'x'of something
        }
    }
```

Any insights appreciated.

edit: here's my isLegalNumber() method

```
bool        isLegalNumber   (const std::map<std::string,std::string>&
                            map,
                 const std::string& varName,
                 float&         value
                )
{
  float     temp;
  char*     cPtr;
  std::map<std::string,std::string>::const_iterator
        iter    = map.find(varName);

  if  (iter == map.end())
    return(false);

  temp  = strtod(iter->second.c_str(),&cPtr);

  if  ( (*cPtr != '\0') || (cPtr == iter->second.c_str()) )
    return(false);

  value = temp;
  return(true);
}
```

im trying to convert a string/ dictionary into a json, 
the first question would be how to add it into a dictionary, 
and second, how to convert that dictionary into JSON.

basically i want the json to look like

```
{
x1: value of x1, 
x2: value of x2, 
.... 
x7: value of x7
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not totally clear what you're trying to do in your example code. Specifically, I don't know what the string value `variable` is used for. I'm guessing you actually want to define an array of floats. You can also skip the first step where you're setting the value to either 0.0 or `atof(...)` since your `isLegalNumber` function sets it later anyway. e.g.

```
float x[8] = {0.0f};
// Note that arrays in C++ are zero-indexed, so your iteration variable should start at 0
for (int i=0; i<=7; i++) { 
    std::string varName = "x";
    varName.push_back(std::to_string(i+1)); // Append the index
    if ( !isLegalNumber(request.getQuery(), varName, x[i] ) {
        // Error
    } else {
        // Add to JSON structure
    }
}
```

Once you've got that sorted out, for working with JSON in C++, I would strongly recommend using an existing open-source library such as [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json), rather than rolling your own implementation. This will make it much easier to build the JSON structure you need and ensure that it is properly formatted.

That library has quite thorough documentation, and it allows you to define JSON structures using very similar syntax to the actual JSON you're trying to write, e.g.

```
json j2 = {
  {"pi", 3.141},
  {"happy", true},
  {"name", "Niels"},
  // ...
};
```

Or in your specific case, define `json j;` outside the loop, and then in your if case you can do:

```
j[varName] = x[i];
```

And then you can convert it to a string using `std::string s = j.dump();`.

Comment: can you demonstrate how to use it in this case? im super new to C++ and dont really understand that much of the syntax

Comment: but im trying to convert a string/ dictionary into a json, i guess the first question would be how to add it into a dictionary, and second, how to convert that dictionary into JSON.

Comment: so basically i want the json to look like this:
```
{x1: value of x1,
x2: value of x2,
....
x7: value of x7}
```

Comment: thank you, that answered my question for this part!